# timebased scoring algorithm for game

Tags: game-design, algorithm

i am developing a game where user has to find target number using 5 given numbers and 4 operators. the score depends on the type of operators and number of operators used and time.

```
score = typeOperators + noOfOperators + timeScore
```

where `typeOperators` is the sum of score for each type of operator, 1 pt for +,* 2 pt for -, and 3 pt for /.

if all the three operators are used once, `typeOperators` will be 13.
currently, i am thinking of

```
timeScore = max(0, x - timespent)
```

But, the game should avoid the situation where the user finding target number with worst solution but with minimum time gets higher scores.
so the more weightage should be on the `typeOperators` rather than `timeScore`.

can there be any better approach?

Comment: It might be really hard for *us* to suggest something to satisfy *your* vision. I would suggest making a spreadsheet with different time values and number of operators. Then add a function of those things to the spreadsheet and see what score you get for different inputs and how the different scores compare with each other. Try different functions or tweak it until the scores look the way you want them to. I would also suggest implementing it in a MVP of the game to see how it actually *feels*, because raw numbers can only tell you so much.

Comment: What specific problems do you have with your current approach that you'd like us to help you solve? In what specific ways should we try to make it "better"?

Comment: Given the detail given as of now, how about `score = typeOperators + noOfOperators + (timeScore / K)` where `K` is a constant you tweak until the weighting seems good?